# R.java disappeared after adding new png pics in my hdpi folder

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using eclips with the android sdk plug-in, my project was working normally with no errors at all and it was a very clean project, but when i deleted and added pictures (PNG pics) to my hdpi folder, plus i also deleted the ic_launcher, but renamed my new icon as "ic_launcher, but R.java was not generated, I and renamed all the pics in lower case without spaces, and than cleaned the project and made sure every link in xml is correctly renamed, so is there any way to regenerate the R.Java ?

Comment: i think u have error on manifest or xml file

Comment: inside Project --> build Automatically , check it

Comment: I'm sure i don't have any errors because i didn't change anything in my manifest and my xml files :/ i just have one xml linked to a pic and i fixed the link

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to do here;

1. Check if Project --> Build automatically  is on
2. Refresh your layout folder through the right-click action
3. Clean all your projects etc
4. If 2. didn't work, restart Eclipse

While doing all this, keep an eye on your console view, it will report errors if you named some resource invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from **`Project=>Clean`**, i would like to suggest you to check **`Windows => Show View => Error log`**. It may help you. Android Pre compiler shows error there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just reload your project, maybe it helps (close and reopen eclipse)